# Selecting from view and inserting into table Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities called Student and Course. They are stored in tables in the following format

**Student**

| id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | johnny | goode |
| 2 | jane | doe |
| 3 | ted | jones |

**Course**

| id | name | subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Calculus | math |
| 2 | Biology | science |
| 3 | Chemistry | science |

Student and Course have a many-to-many relationship stored in a table called Student_Course

**Student_Course**

| student_id | course_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |

I have a view of Student_Course called v_student_course and it contains the student_id, course_id, and the subject (which is retrieved from the course table).

**v_student_course**

| student_id | course_id | subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Math |
| 2 | 3 | Science |

In my Springboot application, I have a Student class and a Course class which look like this respectively

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student {
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected @Id int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    protected String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    protected String lastName;

    //getters and setters left out for this example
}
```

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Course")
public class Course{
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected @Id int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    protected String name;

    @Column(name = "subject")
    protected String subject;

    //getters and setters left out for this example
}
```

I have to represent the many to many relationship between Student and Course by showing what courses a student is assigned to. However, all selects must be done using the view v_student_course and all inserts/updates must be done using the table Student_Course.

1. Should I do this using a ManyToMany annotation? However, I've noticed that this will cause NullPointerExceptions if the Student is not associated with a Course. Or should I make a separate class for the bridge relationship called StudentCourse.java?
2. How do I state that selects must come from a different table/view than inserts/updates?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by setting adding this code to the Student class

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Course.class)
@JoinTable(name = "v_student_course",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
protected List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
```

I added this code to the Course class

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
protected List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
```

I then added this to my StudentRepository interface

```
@Modifying
@Query (
    value = "INSERT INTO student_course (student_id, course_id) "
            "VALUES (:studentId, :courseId)",
    nativeQuery = true
)
public void saveStudentCourse(@Param("studentId") String studentId,
                              @Param("courseId") String courseId);
```

Now whenever I search for a Student, it also selects the students associated courses from v_student_course, but when I insert a new student course association, it gets inserted directly into the table.